# How to receive all sensors list (include not supported)

Tags: android, sensors

I want to enumerate **all** sensors supported by [Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) and verify if my device support it or not (include Step Counter, Game Rotation Vector, Geomagnetic Rotation Vector, Significant Motion, etc.)

I use `Sensor.TYPE_ALL` to receive all sensors, code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enumarte_sensors);

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    TextView tvAvailableSensors;

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    tvAvailableSensors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_AvailableSensors);
    tvAvailableSensors.setText("Sensors status:\n\n");

    for (Sensor s : sensors)
    {
        boolean regSuccess = sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(s.getType()), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        tvAvailableSensors.append(s.getName() + " (" + s.getType() + ")  " + regSuccess + "\n");
        if (regSuccess) sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(s.getType()));
    }
}
```

But I receive status only for few sensors: Accelerometer, Ambient Light, Gyroscope, Magnetic Field, Orientation, Rotation Vector, Linear Acceleration and Gravity.
(And I didn't receive any status about Step Detector\Counter, Significant Motion, etc.)

Someone knows how can I verify which sensor really supported on my device and which no?

**EDIT:**

To be clear: I know my device not support all sensors but I want to receive list with all available sensors and status which one I support and which no.

For example, I have Nexus 10, so I should receive list like this:

> Accelerometer      True
>
> Ambient Ligh       True
>
> ...
>
> Step Counter       False
>
> Significant Motion False

Comment: What evidence do you have that your device supports the sensors that were not returned?

Comment: Are you running 4.4 on your test device? Step counter was only introduced in KitKat

Comment: I not mean my device really support them, this what I want to check. I want to receive list with all Google sensors and to know which one my device support and which one not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think such an API is not available, you need to check for each of the sensor type in code:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) != null){
  // Success! There's a magnetometer.
  }
else {
  // Failure! No magnetometer.
  }
```

And the documentation quotes these type of sensors:

```
    TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR   
    TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR TYPE_GRAVITY TYPE_GYROSCOPE   
    TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED TYPE_LIGHT TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION   
    TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED
    TYPE_ORIENTATION    TYPE_PRESSURE TYPE_PROXIMITY
    TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY    TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR
    TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION TYPE_STEP_COUNTER    TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR
    TYPE_TEMPERATURE
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy, of course it's right answer but I search for more dynamic answer. I not want to update my app any time Google adding new sensor...

Comment: Maybe you need to write a server from which client gets the list of all sensors. This server would need to be updated whenever new sensor is added or it could read from some configuration (which could then be updated). Your app in this case would not need to updated.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late, but as this question was pretty high ranked in a search.
You can use

```
sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

to get a list of all sensors available on the current device.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858161/display-an-android-sensors-list) stack overflow article for more details